# how to: findByProperty on two fields in typo3 v4.5.30?

Tags: search, repository, typo3, extbase

I want to search for records which match on two fields with two supplied objects,
for example

```
 $cnt = $this->usedCouponRepository->findByUser($validvip)->toArray() ;
 $cnt2 = $this->usedCouponRepository->findByCoupon($validcoupon)->toArray() ;
```

get interesection, (find how many times validvip pairs up with  validcoupon in the usedcoupon table)
  a call like this would be it -

```
$cnt3 = $this->usedCouponRepository->findByUserAndCoupon($validcoupon,$validuser);
```

is there a magic function to do this or some other efficient way?  I'd hate to just loop over the first looking for a match in code.
 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no "extbase magic" doing this job for you. You have to implement it yourself. But lucky you, its not that hard. Just add a method to your repository like this one:

```
public function findByUserAndCoupon($validcoupon, $validuser) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->equals('user', $validuser),
            $query->equals('coupon', validcoupon)
        )
    );
    $result = $query->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Now you can call this like you tried before. The strings `'user'` and `'coupon'` in the logicalAnd Statement have to be the fieldnames of the database.

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I did.  Thanks.